# Outputting the name of the column in SQLite

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have created two tables and now I want to find the movie that yielded the highest revenue for each platform(Hulu, Disney and Netflix). The problem here is I do not know how to output the names of the platform as it is a column title. Can anyone help me?

```
CREATE TABLE "StreamedMovies" (
 "Title" TEXT, 

 "Netflix" INTEGER, -- 1 if the movie is streamed in this platform, 0 otherwise

 "Hulu" INTEGER, -- 1 if the movie is streamed in this platform, 0 otherwise


 "Disney" INTEGER, -- 1 if the movie is streamed in this platform, 0 otherwise

 "ScreenTime" REAL, 

 PRIMARY KEY("Title")
)

CREATE TABLE "MovieData" (
 "Title" TEXT, 
 "Genre" TEXT, 
 "Director" TEXT, 
 "Casting" TEXT, 
 "Rating" REAL, 
 "Revenue" REAL,
 PRIMARY KEY("Title")
)
```

Comment: Bad designs lead to complex queries and bad performance. Change the design of your db. All you need is 1 column instead of 3 (or more if you want to include more platforms).

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to write a case statement.

```
select
  Title,
  case
    when Netflix == 1 then 'Netflix'
    when Hulu = 1 then 'Hulu'
    when Disney = 1 then 'Disney'
  end as Platform
from StreamedMovies
```

This indicates a flaw in your design. A number of flaws. For example, there's nothing stopping a row from having multiple platforms. Or no platforms. Or having a platform set to 42.

Instead, add a platforms table and a [join table](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) to indicate which movies are streaming on which platforms.

While we're at it we'll fix some other issues.

- Titles can change. Use a simple integer primary key.
- Don't quote column and table names, it makes them case sensitive.
- Declare your foreign keys.
- Use not null to require important data.

```
-- The platforms available for streaming.
create table platforms (
  id integer primary key,
  name text not null
);

insert into platforms (id, name)
  values ('Netflix'), ('Hulu'), ('Disney+');

-- The movies.
create table movies (
  id integer primary key,
  title text not null
);

insert into movies (title) values ('Bad Taste');

-- A join table for which platforms movies are streaming on.
create table streamed_movies (
  movie_id integer not null references movies,
  platform_id integer not null references platforms
);

insert into streamed_movies (movie_id, platform_id) values (1, 1), (1, 3);

select
  movies.title, platforms.name
from streamed_movies sm
join movies on sm.movie_id = movies.id
join platforms on sm.platform_id = platforms.id

title      name   
---------  -------
Bad Taste  Netflix
Bad Taste  Disney+
```